# Is there a way to have a version of std::atomic's compare_exchange_strong method that exchanges on inequality?

Tags: c++, atomic, stdatomic, compare-and-swap

I have an atomic type where I need to atomically compare it with a value, and if the two values are *not equal* then exchange the value of the atomic.

Put another way, where `compare_exchange_strong` essentially does this operation atomically:

```
if (atomic_value == expected)
    atomic_value = desired;
```

...I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
if (atomic_value != expected)
    atomic_value = desired;
```

(Yes, I know `compare_exchange_strong` compares using bitwise equality, not the `==` operator. And I know the value of `expected` gets assigned when the comparison fails. This was just for illustration purposes. In my use case I don't need the value of the atomic regardless of the result of the comparison.)

Is there any way to do this without having to fall back on using a lock instead of `std::atomic`?

Comment: It'll be interesting to see if any of the proposed answers get compiled optimally on an LL/SC architecture, where at the machine level it really is just a matter of reversing a test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
auto observed = atomic_value.load();
for (;;)
{
    if (observed == expected){
       break; // no exchange
    }
    if (atomic_value.compare_exchange_weak(observed, desired)) { 
       break; // successfully exchanged observed with desired
    }
}
```

---

Sure it is suboptimal on architectures where HW has LL/SC, as C++ does not expose it. With LL/SC can have arbitrary condition.

Comment: Doesn't this have a race condition since the comparison and exchange are not part of the same atomic operation? Another thread could change `atomic_value` between the call to `load()` and the comparison, or between the comparison and the exchange.

Comment: @BriBri: If another thread changes the value, then `compare_exchange_weak` returns `false` because `atomic_value` no longer equals `observed`.  It loads the new value into `observed`, and we continue the loop to compare the new value against `expected`.  This all seems correct and I don't see any race.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <random>

std::atomic<int> atomVal;

int store_if_not_equal(int desired)
{
    while (true)    // or maxloop....
    {
        int expected = desired;

        if (atomVal.compare_exchange_strong(expected, desired))
        {
            // values matched - do nothing
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //expected now contains the "current value"
            // another thread could have sneaked in and changed it,
            // so only replace it if it still matches
            if (atomVal.compare_exchange_strong(expected, desired))
            {
                // success
                return 1;
            }
        }

    // if we arrive here, retry
    }
}

int main()
{
    atomVal.store(rand());
    return store_if_not_equal(2);
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/qWTP7canf

Comment: Won't the first call to `compare_exchange_strong` set `atomVal` to `desired` if the comparison passes? `atomVal` should not be modified if its value equals `expected`.

Comment: It's "modified" to the same value.

Comment: This may work for some cases, but in my use case `expected` and `desired` are not necessarily the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the loop one ordinarily uses with compare-and-exchange, but instead of looping until the (new) expected value matches, loop **either** until it matches (and the store happens) or it equals the value in your `!= expected` condition, since that’s the case in which you needn’t do anything.  (Obviously don’t make the initial value be that “unless” value so that you can’t “succeed” the first time.)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Could you clarify your answer?

Comment: @BriBri Exchanging a value with itself is a nop, so just do a `variable.exchange(expected_value)` and if the return value is not equal to `expected_value`, then do your thing.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Pretty sure you can't use `.exchange()` unconditionally here, otherwise you're letting other threads see a value that maybe shouldn't have been there.  That's only safe if `expected == desired`, i.e. a plain store to set the value whether or not it was that already.  Or if the specific use-case makes it ok to set `variable = expected` temporarily before storing `desired`, i.e. other threads are also trying to do this, rather than some other operation on the shared variable.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay, I misunderstood the question. I thought that the value being conditionally assigned was `expected`. (I.e., `if (variable != expected) { variable = expected; }`)

Comment: @RaymondChen: Yeah, took me a second to spot that, too.  The usual reason for that pattern is to avoid writers (which invalidate the cache line for other cores), so I don't think you'd normally want to turn that into a `.exchange` either.  Although maybe `.exchange` after a read-only check, if you need to verify that you did actually win the race to change the variable.